# Display message notification instead error message log Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8

In my cart observer, I block 1 item in the cart and then display a notification to the user something like "*you could select just one item*" the problem that it appears to be the error log Magento first then when I return to the home page. I find my message displayed. I just want to display it in my page and not also in the error log page or display it in the cart page without adding a second item of course.

Observer.php :

```
class Amir_Prince_Model_ObserverCountItemCart{
    public function limiter_panier(Varient_Event_Observer $observer) {

    $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
    $quote = $session->getQuote();

    if($quote->getItemsCount()>=1){
    $message = 'You can select only one item.';
    $session->addError($message); 
    // Mage::thrownewException($message); // the log error commented
    throw new Exception($message);// the frontend notification

      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to remove `throw new Exception($message);` to stop getting log messages in the exception log. Its also better to use the methods:

```
Mage::getSingleton(‘core/session’)->addNotice(‘Notice message’);
Mage::getSingleton(‘core/session’)->addError(‘Error message’); 
Mage::getSingleton(‘core/session’)->addWarning(‘Warning message’); 
Mage::getSingleton(‘core/session’)->addSuccess(‘Success message’);
```

Depending on how you want the message to appear.

Comment: This method i'll put it where ? in my observer !

i tried to replace:  throw new Exception($message); with Mage::getSingleton(‘core/session’)->addNotice(‘Notice message’); but it doesnt work

Comment: Is this an ajax action? If you refresh the page does the message show up?

Comment: When i replaced  throw new Exception($message); with Mage::getSingleton(‘core/session’)->addNotice(‘Notice message’); I got an Error.
No, I want to display it only once each time the user want to add a 2nd item to the cart , I am willing to display it in cart page.
here is my process in 4 phases:
1)Index.phtml->2)Result.phtml->3)Cart.phtml->4)Checkout.phtml
in phase 2)Result.phtml i do a action button to add to the cart.

Comment: what was the error?

Comment: I verified my code, i havnt error now but my observer dont work, i mean : my observer dont block the add.